# What can I do to try to see if I have overlooked or under-appreciated the acceptability of answers so that I can accept them?

Tags: support, statistics, accepted-answer

I checked my stats:

- 'user:12102 is:question` yields **2,338** posts.
- adding `isanswered:yes` yields **1,985** posts or 85% (the whole site is currently around 88%)
- adding `answers:2...` (two or more answers) yields **686** posts or 35% of those with answers
- removing that and instead adding `hasaccepted:yes` yields **1,538** or **of all my questions with at least one answer, I've accepted an answer on only 77% of them.**

That's better than the site as a whole; 8,311 / 13,396 = 62%, but nonetheless I think it can and should be increased at least somewhat as part of good question stewardship practices and site hygiene.

**Question:** What can I do to try to see if I have overlooked or under-appreciated the *acceptability of answers* so that I can accept them?

I've decided to self-impose a new *temporary rule* that for every new question I post I must accept an answer somewhere else on the site. There will likely be some low-hanging fruit, but during this "campaign"

#### Please feel free to ping me

on any page where there's an answer that feels like it is acceptable and yet hasn't been. These will sometimes be your own answers, that's fine!

Besides that, what else can I do?

If two answers are equally good the advice I've had in the past is that it's not necessary to accept one based on an arbitrary coin-toss or similar, but maybe if it's 60:40 I should just *go for it?*

Comment: This one seems pretty straightforward https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40298/which-deep-space-spacecraft-had-main-dish-antennas-that-were-perforated-or-made/40305#40305

Comment: @OrganicMarble yep, the other answer is not a deep-space spacecraft. Done! btw I'm anticipating a flood, so I wrote "...on any page where..." so they don't all end up here.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted checkmark is meant to indicate which answer was most helpful to you in understanding the issue, so the best thing you can do for those that you haven't accepted an answer on is look and see if one of the answers addressed your question.

If multiple did, which one was most helpful? If one wasn't more helpful than the others, you don't have to accept one.